# Python | FastApi/Uvicorn: How to pass a Queue to uvicorn.run(..)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, fastapi, uvicorn

**What I tried**

I tried first to pass it on as a parameter somehow within `uvicorn.run(...)` but have not been successfully on it (I didn't found a general placeholder I could use for it).

I also tried to use a global variable, but it seems to me that uvicorn run on a separate process, thereby the Queue address did not stayed constant.

Then I tried to pass on the memory storage reference of the queue (as string) via environment variable, but then I was not able to transfer that string address back to an object to use it within the server.

**Does anyone know how to solve this and basically pass on a Queue to the (FastApi)uvicorn server?**

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process
import uvicorn as uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect

class WSServer:
    def __init__(self): pass

    def run(self, queue):
        # how can I pass the --> queue <-- inside the uvicorn(FastApi) server?
        uvicorn.run("server:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8081, reload=True, access_log=False) 

main_queue: Queue = Queue() 
proc = Process(target=WSServer().run,name="Process: Simple Server",args=(main_queue,))
proc.start()

------------

app = FastAPI()

@app.websocket("/")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            msg = await websocket.receive_text()
            ...
            # here it would be lovely if I could use the "queue"...
```

Comment: You may try to to add the queue as a `Value` or `Array`, I think these can be shared between processes when passing the object to the Process args. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: But... isn't the Queue shared between process by nature? Docs: `Returns a process shared queue implemented using a pipe and a few locks/semaphores. When a process first puts an item on the queue a feeder thread is started which transfers objects from a buffer into the pipe.` Did you try to access the queue normally?

Comment: Yes, uvicorn will make use of multiple processes, so this approach is most likely to fail. Why do you want to run several parallel FastAPI instances? What are you trying to accomplish, what problem do you want to solve?

Comment: Snapper?  Same question, what type of functionality you wanna achieve using this queue. Is it like some user queue or file queue?

Comment: The idea is to launch multiple different processes within the main file. One process would be the server. Via a queue would I like to be able to communicate from the server back to the main file (i.e. in case the server will close down soon -> send a queue msg from the server to the main file which will than terminate all other running processes) @M.O.

Comment: Ʌ @developer6811

Comment: In that case, there is no need for your worker processes to run uvicorn. I would **highly** recommend looking into Celery (or a similar project), which is designed to do just what you are after.

Comment: Agree with @M.O.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced exactly the same problem and as I'm building a prototype going for Celery seemed like an overkill... I managed to solve it by storing the queue in the internal state of the app:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import uvicorn


def webapp(q):
    app = FastAPI()
    app.state.q = q

    @app.get("/")
    async def main(request: Request):
        request.app.state.q.put("item 1")
        return {"text": "hello"}

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, log_level="info")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()

    webapp_proc = Process(target=webapp, args=(q, ))
    webapp_proc.start()
    
    print("waiting for something to appear in the queue...")
    item = q.get()
    print(f"here: {item}")
```

Comment: why did you use `request.app` instead of just `app`?